# Route model binding select specific columns with relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Route:

```
Route::get('/posts/{post}', [PostController::class, 'show']);
```

Controller:

```
public function show(Post $post){
    $postData = $post->load(['author' => function($query){
        $query->select('post_id', 'name');
    }])
    ->get(['title', 'desc', 'created_date'])
    ->toArray();
}
```

This returns all the posts in the database, While I only want to get the selected post passed to the `show` function.

So if I visit `/posts/3`, It should show data related to the post with `id` = 3, not all posts.

The result should be an array with only the selected post.

Comment: I think you only receive 1 post, but accidentally load more by calling the `load()` function. Can you do `dd($post->toArray());` as first line in the `show()` function to verify?

Comment: @Techno That's right, but I need the `author` data and `with('author')` can't be used

Comment: Then I think you need to do this: `$post->author()->select('post_id', 'name')->first()` If you don't mind which columns, you can also do `$post->author`

Comment: And if you find yourself needing the author most of the times when you need a post, you can add `$with=['author']` to post model like described in https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-by-default

Comment: why do you need `$post` to only have certain attributes and not all its attributes?

Comment: @lagbox Because I will use a loop for the post data and use the index for translation. So extra indexes are not needed and will require extra work

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use `get()` function on the model.

```
public function show(Post $post) 
{
    $post->load(['author' => function ($query) {
        $query->select(['post_id', 'name']);
    ]);
    dd($post->toArray());
}
```

Btw, the author shouldn't have a post_id, because author can have multiple posts. you should update the database structure or you are doing wrong in the controller. (my bad, Thanks @techno)

Comment: I did not know you could add columns to a relationship-load like that. That's really neat! Do you have a link to the docs to this feature(`relation:column1,column2`)? Or did you find that out watching a video?

Comment: Been checking the docs and found it in https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns

Comment: Is there a way to filter the `post` data to get specific columns only?

Comment: `$post->select('id', 'title');` if you are running a query and if you already have a model instance and want to keep specific columns, use `$post->only([])` method.

Answer (score 0):

When you are inside the Controller you already have the Post you want. If you call `get` you are getting all posts with a new query.

To select specific columns from a relationship, you can do it like this:

```php
public function show(Post $post)
{
   $post->load('author:id,name,age'); // load columns id, name, age from author
}
```

Notice that including the `id` is required.

To specify columns for the Post, there's no way to do it per route, the only way is to override how Laravel resolves the implicit binding. For that, you can add this in your `Post` model class:

```php
public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null)
{
    return $this->whereKey($value)->select(['id', 'body', 'author_id'])->firstOrFail();
}
```

Notice that including the `author_id` is required to load the Author afterwards inside the Controller method. Also keep in mind this will affect all routes where you implicitly load a Post.